# public bool method Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to `void'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Im implementing google play sdk to my android game and so far i've done log in and leaderboard part but adding achievements is causing me a little trouble because im using public bool method to make my life easier for future updates and mark the achievements as unlocked.

For some reason im getting this error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to`void'**

```
public bool unlockAchievement(string achievementName, string achievementID) {
    if(loggedIn == true) {
        Social.ReportProgress(achievementID, 100.0f, (bool success) => {
            return success;
        });
    }
    else return false;
}
```

I think i covered any loose ends but yet im getting this error.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit:**

It seams to work like this

```
public bool unlockAchievement(string achievementName, string achievementID) {
    bool actionDone = false;
    if(loggedIn == true) {
        Social.ReportProgress(achievementID, 100.0f, (bool success) => {
            if(success) actionDone = true;
            else actionDone = false;
        });
        return actionDone;
    }
    else return actionDone;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Be warned, the solution in your edit only works if the callback passed to Social.ReportProgress is run synchronously. If that method does not get called immediately before ReportProgress returns, actionDone will remain false, and when the callback does get called, nothing will happen.

Comment: Yes i was thinking about that, i have to do some testing and see how it will turn out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda is an enclosed method, so the context for the return statement is the lambda method, not `unlockAchievement`.

You'll probably want to refactor your code to use a callback, i.e. something like this:

```
public void unlockAchievement(string achievementName, string achievementID, Action<bool> callback) {
    if(loggedIn == true) {
        Social.ReportProgress(achievementID, 100.0f, (bool success) => {
            callback(success);
        });
    }
    else callback(false);
}
```